# SQL optional values breaking statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do simple insert in php and MySQL.
The HTML form has 3 fields with 1st one being mandatory and other 2 optional.
their names being :

> name, address and phoneno

table name is  **users** : **id**(*int*)|**name**(*varchar*)|**address**(*varchar*)|**phoneno**(*int*) , **id** is *primary-key* and *auto-increment*
and all except name and id are *allow-nulls*

assuming i have connection created  and held in **$con**  ,providing a value  just for name and submitting the form

```
$name   =   $_POST['name']?$_POST['name']:NULL;
$address=   $_POST['address']?$_POST['address']:NULL;
$phoneno=   $_POST['phoneno']?$_POST['phoneno']:NULL;


$q="INSERT INTO users (name,address,phoneno)
VALUES('{$name}','{$address}',{$phoneno})";

if(mysql_query($q,$con)){
echo "data inserted successfully";
}
else{
echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
}
```

Is giving me 
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never do this in production environments! But for learning, try this:

```
$name   =   $_POST['name']?$_POST['name']:'NULL';
$address=   $_POST['address']?$_POST['address']:'NULL';
$phoneno=   $_POST['phoneno']?$_POST['phoneno']:'NULL';

$q="INSERT INTO users (name,address,phoneno) VALUES('$name','$address',$phoneno)";

if(mysql_query($q,$con)){
     echo "data inserted successfully";
}
else{
     echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
}
```

1. You have to use 'NULL' as string
2. Do not wrap variables with {}. this is only needed when you use object properties like {$obj->foo}

There are some other serious security issues in this code like sql injection. So never do this in production environments!

Comment: Yes! now its working well.I was just getting started with the dynamic page generation so left aside the security implications for brevity ,but yes in production will be sure to observe this , again Thanks ! a lot for helping.